# How does python and c signal handlers work together?

Tags: python, c, linux, signals

Both Python and C allow users to install a signal handler. However, if a Python program calls C code, and that C code installs a C signal handler, then the Python program also installs a Python signal handler for the same signal, how will that signal be handled afterwards?

More specifically, what happens when users call `signal.signal` in Python? Does Python install, in addition to a Python signal handler, a C signal handler which will replace the old C signal handler? If so, where is the old C signal handler returned in the Python environment?

`man sigaction` says:

> If `oldact` is non-NULL, the previous action is saved in `oldact`.

But Python `signal.signal` returns the old Python signal handler not the old C signal handler.

Comment: Are they in different processes or are you calling a library through ctypes?

Comment: @stark In the same process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Python discards the old signal handler.  Python does install its own C handler [here (Python source code)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62be74290aca26d16f3f55ece7ff6dad14e60e8d/Modules/signalmodule.c#L461).  This handler manages the Python signaling.

`PyOS_setsig` does return the old C handler, but the linked line discards it.  The Python implementation of `signal.signal` also returns a 'previous' handler, but it is only tracking an internal list (see the variable `Handlers`). It is unaware of any C handlers.